# foreach error "could not find function "%do%""

Tags: r

I'm getting

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "%do%""
```

when running this code

```
....
niters = 1000
mFR <- foreach(i=1:iters, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
          foreach(j=1:iters, .combine=c) %do% {
              mp2 <- mp[sample(1:1e6, iters)]
              fexist = 0
              if (mp2[j]>mR12[i]) {
                   Frv = 1
                   fexist = 1
              } else if (mp2[j]<=mRy2[i]) {
                   Frv = 0
                   fexist = 1
              }  else {
                   if (mRy2[i]>mR12[i]) {
                      Frv = 1
                   } else {
                      fexist = 1
                      b = mDMDuc1[i]/(1-mR12[i]/mRy2[i])
                      m = -b/mRy2[i]
                      DMDp = m*mp2[j] + b
                      Frv = (DMDp - 0)/(mDMDc2[i] - 0)
                   }
              }
              if (fexist==1) {
                 mFR <- matrix(Frv, ncol=1, nrow = 1)
                 mFR
              }
           }
}
```

Any idea why this error happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your parallel workers each operate in a clean R session, so you have to load the `foreach` package in each worker.

Try adding `.packages="foreach"` to your first line, i.e.:

```
mFR <- foreach(i=1:iters, .combine=rbind, .packages="foreach") %dopar% ...{
```

---

Additional note: the `foreach` package defines an operator `%:%` that is designed to streamline this type of nested for loop.

To learn more, use

```
library(foreach)
vignette("nested")
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this at the beggining of the code

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(iterators)
library(doParallel)
```

but first install all the packages! :)